# usort in php failed with duplicate records

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I am using the following code to sort (descending order) a 3-D array:

```
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        return $b["user_points"] - $a["user_points"];
    }
    usort($myArray, "cmp");
```

But the sorted array looks like this:

```
user_id user_name   user_points
CTEST111    TST111  175.00
CTEST100    TST100  110.00
CTEST801    TST801  100.00
CTEST401    TST401  100.00
CTEST901    TST901  63.33
CTEST501    TST501  63.33
CTEST102    TST02   64.25
CTEST104    TST04   55.00
CTEST101    TST01   52.82
CTEST202    TST202  42.65
CTEST201    TST201  42.60
CTEST302    TST302  42.11
```

Rows 5,6,7 are not sorted correctly. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the return type of your `cmp` function. You are returning float values instead of ints.
If you look at [PHP manual for usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) there's a warning:

**Caution**
Returning non-integer values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

This code should do the work

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a["user_points"] == $b["user_points"]) 
    {
       return 0;
    }
    return ($a["user_points"] > $b["user_points"]) ? -1 : 1;
}
usort($myArray, "cmp");
```